# Chrome extension looping through javascript object not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am building a chrome extension and I am running the following script:

```
var group = {
        'object1': {
            option1: '',
            option2: ''
        },
        'object2': {
            option1: '',
            option2: ''
        }
    };

chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: " \
        var group_array = [" + Object.keys(group) + "]; \
        console.log(group_array[0]); \
    "
});
```

For some reason, the `console.log` returns that `object1` is not defined. I wanted the `console.log` to return the name of the first object in `group`, so it should return `object1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just test it. The problem is:

```
"["+['object1','object2']+"]" -> "[object1,object2]"
```

So

```
var group_array = [object1, object2];
```

And if you eval the string directly, the object1 and object2 will be treated as variable instead of string, and since there is not variable named object1 and object2, the evaluation failed.

To achieve what you want, you can loop the array of Object.keys(group), and append keys to the code one by one, or you can directly using JSON.stringify to parse the result to a string array:

```
" \
    var group_array = " + JSON.stringify(Object.keys(group)) + "; \
    console.log(group_array[0]); \
"
```